# Maven is not packaging updated property version in packaged jar file

Tags: maven, maven-3

I have an application with a dependency. When I am trying to build it using -Dprop.name=value, it is not showing up in pom.xml inside jar.

My project structure:

```
`module -> util
library -> utillib: this uses util module
application -> app: this uses utillib`
```

pom.xml in my utillib

```
`<properties>
<util.version>2.0-SNAPSHOT</util.version>
</properties>`
```

I am using following command for release:
`mvn clean install -Dutil.version=2.0`

When this command generates the jar, it is not a fat jar(as required), but it contains a pom.xml which still shows `util.version=2.0-SNAPSHOT`

Now, I am compiling my application:
mvn clean install and this uses 2.0-SNAPSHOT version of util instead of 2.0 version, which is expected.

I was expecting that `mvn clean install -Dutil.version=2.0` should remove all occurences of util.version with 2.0 instead of 2.0-SNAPSHOT everywhere in the whole chain.

Comment: Which Maven Version etc. JDK, Plugin versions etc. do you use? And why do you need the property?